# Unable to connect to redis container from a different docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, docker-network, redis-cluster

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
 redis:
  image: redis:latest
  container_name: redis
  hostname: redis
  ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
  networks:
      - mynetwork
  volumes:
    - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
  command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

 DServer:
  image: DServerImage
  networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

i have a container name DServer and a redis container, both are connected with a bridge network,i can enter into redis by login into the redis container > redis-cli>

but when i run client list i cant see the DServer ip address in the client list.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=3 addr=127.0.0.1:48174 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379 fd=9 name= age=4 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 ssub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=26 qbuf-free=20448 argv-mem=10 multi-mem=0 rbs=1024 r
```

containers are up by docker-compose file in which i have defined DServer to be depends on redis also in redis.conf file i have done this conf

```
bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
```

i can see that both are connected to same network by checking in docker inspect network name but not in client list

how can i fix this or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you share your docker-compose file and the Redis connection URL?

Comment: Hi, i am sharing the docker-compose file not sure abt redis connection url, could you please elaborate a little?

Added file in question itse;f.
version: '2'
services:
 redis:
  image: redis:latest
  container_name: redis
  hostname: redis
  ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
  networks:
      - mynetwork
  volumes:
    - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
  command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

 DServer:
  image: DServerImage
  networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

Comment: How do you tell DServer how to connect to Redis, i.e. hostname, port, etc?

Comment: hostname- redis, Port-6379,    maybe i am not making the connection right, can u please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Redis port like this

```
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
```

So then the same networks can access the Redis by calling `6379`

---

**FYI**

This is what I use in my Redis local

```
  app_redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    container_name: app_redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'app_redis:/data'
    networks:
      - app-network
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
```

Comment: i have also tried with this port, how will the connection actually established?
are you able to connect to redis-cli by login into the other container and then running redis-cli?

Comment: By adding `REDIS_HOST=app_redis` and `REDIS_PORT=6379` in .env. and calling them in `database.php`